# How can i remove a div with jQuery?

Tags: css

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 999999999; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;"></div>
```

I'm trying to remove this entire thing with jQuery but i don't know how to actually refer to the style or div, i don't really know what i should call it.

It doesn`t have a dot between < and div, i had to do that so the site would show it.

Comment: why do you set  `opacity: 0` ??? if tou set `opacity:0` the `div` does not seem anyway....

Comment: I didn't do it, i'm trying to remove that, it's an add.

Comment: Edit your question and add the parent of the div. Try to select the parent of the div and then remove the child.

Comment: there is no parent? atleast not one that i can see.

Answer (score 0):

give id or class to that div and than you can hide that div with jQuery

example:

```
<div id="block" class="blabla">...</div>

<script>$("#block").hide(); // or (".blabla").hide(); </script>
```

Comment: I'm doing it with tampermonkey. It's a manual adblock that`s also useful for other things. I just need to know how i can remove it.

Comment: try what? i can't add to the code and there's no id or class that i can refer to

Comment: and i'm not using css, i'm using jQuery and it runs each time i get on the website because of tampermonkey

Comment: @SirCoCoNUT But if you use `$("div").hide();` it hide all the divs in site

Comment: allright, i'll try that but it'`s probably gonna destroy the site. yeah, it just wipes the whole site.

Comment: https://filmehd.net/euphoria-2017.html this is the site, ignore the movie, i just clicked a random one. on the first player there`s that add when you click the openload window. if you inspect element the add it's what i wrote about in my question.

Answer (score 0):

For removing:
**You can do it in css:(or add to the div's style)**

```
div{
   display:none
}
```

**`Div`'s style:**

```
<div style="display:none;..."></div>
```

Comment: I mean try my answer.. this is my answer